# Error when using auto.arima

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I've read in a quarterly time series with one y variable and 16 x variables (potential features):

[image]

> dput(y)
>   structure(c(683.705, 719.185, 702.629, 764.002, 700.136, 745.584, 
>   709.971, 772.7, 700.4, 743.2, 710.37, 787.77, 721.41), .Tsp = c(2015.5, 
>   2018.5, 4), class = "ts")
>
> dput(x)
>   structure(c(1.220143613, 1.388522462, 1.352190798, 1.480635668, 
>   1.252272718, 1.426825136, 1.39887715, 1.555181393, 1.26733429, 
>   1.485546705, 1.418013704, 1.625863455, 1.349309328, 0.663309841, 
>   0.800692159, 0.80249114, 0.79917556, 0.748589842, 0.886269651, 
>   0.836515917, 0.83490775, 0.740478616, 0.86933603, 0.857231236, 
>   0.961783817, 0.847820055, 1.04874566, 1.345967802, 1.215567925, 
>   1.35488868, 1.12523918, 1.437960619, 1.301372528, 1.46734515, 
>   1.173696685, 1.494303761, 1.333366404, 1.541677577, 1.268886, 
>   0.175354574, 0.225103645, 0.22813886, 0.206806755, 0.182533372, 
>   0.259380263, 0.272812242, 0.251983473, 0.229185702, 0.293885407, 
>   0.300491295, 0.278908167, 0.254046095, 1.114534588, 1.172812911, 
>   1.13411702, 1.273940617, 1.145002766, 1.226815513, 1.193418333, 
>   1.328425146, 1.159223025, 1.283069376, 1.209939735, 1.383903662, 
>   1.238169287, 1.91196801, 2.05037978, 1.958889215, 2.106706851, 
>   2.072945866, 2.220495633, 2.094353505, 2.261800048, 2.150224784, 
>   2.287895922, 2.204648555, 2.434225111, 2.350482186, 3.279372171, 
>   3.440972561, 3.162408413, 3.488016112, 3.30084279, 3.57702884, 
>   3.27785305, 3.665974148, 3.372229627, 3.617774174, 3.312265831, 
>   3.749715037, 3.485845823, 0.137117739, 0.172612268, 0.186411335, 
>   0.166548778, 0.16675303, 0.207811097, 0.21317019, 0.191706463, 
>   0.184454699, 0.234095261, 0.239296476, 0.210449299, 0.207025344, 
>   0.042611769, 0.045950063, 0.045401157, 0.04659233, 0.042642024, 
>   0.04579075, 0.046362637, 0.047999424, 0.042791878, 0.04706386, 
>   0.045950785, 0.049612339, 0.044579917, 0.023441531, 0.026897241, 
>   0.027573774, 0.026790346, 0.025896592, 0.029521505, 0.028092914, 
>   0.026997154, 0.02460974, 0.027395344, 0.028089357, 0.02947261, 
>   0.027252008, 0.03488463, 0.041442488, 0.03902228, 0.040748437, 
>   0.036480739, 0.043188657, 0.040852975, 0.043296023, 0.03759708, 
>   0.044201767, 0.04108875, 0.043862541, 0.039439714, 0.005597962, 
>   0.006785218, 0.006841835, 0.006129854, 0.005830813, 0.007482139, 
>   0.008010844, 0.007250128, 0.006932114, 0.008344492, 0.008756133, 
>   0.007940072, 0.007625547, 0.039875904, 0.040380557, 0.039783523, 
>   0.042529875, 0.039766915, 0.04084227, 0.040291611, 0.043290815, 
>   0.03979658, 0.042058691, 0.04065321, 0.044462021, 0.041252474, 
>   0.071041604, 0.073835684, 0.071410253, 0.074936403, 0.075457576, 
>   0.076596967, 0.074681333, 0.078146859, 0.076342091, 0.077826613, 
>   0.076457574, 0.081873291, 0.080637801, 0.111989783, 0.11239112, 
>   0.106276211, 0.11303708, 0.109911315, 0.113246257, 0.106750719, 
>   0.114803854, 0.109432506, 0.111902632, 0.104682394, 0.11318588, 
>   0.10859087, 0.004366597, 0.00531759, 0.005590917, 0.004960056, 
>   0.005077482, 0.006127668, 0.006349584, 0.005678088, 0.005722768, 
>   0.006743787, 0.006952184, 0.006075801, 0.006113069), .Dim = c(13L, 
>   16L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", 
>   "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x11", "x12", "x13", "x14", "x15", 
>   "x16")), .Tsp = c(2015.5, 2018.5, 4), class = c("mts", "ts", 
>   "matrix"))

Transform data into time series:

```
y <- ts(Macro[1:13,2:2], start = c(2015, 3), frequency = 4) 
x <- ts(Macro[1:13,3:18], start = c(2015, 3), frequency = 4)
```

A Dickey-Fuller test indicates no stationarity:

```
adf.test(y,
     alternative = c("stationary", "explosive"),
     k = trunc((length(y)-1)^(1/3)))
```

returns:

```
data:  y
Dickey-Fuller = -6.1083, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(y, alternative = c("stationary", "explosive"), k = trunc((length(y) -  :
p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

A seasonal check indicates some seasonal effect:

```
stl_y = stl(y,  s.window = "periodic")
stl_y

Components
           seasonal    trend   remainder
2015 Q3 -28.542501 710.4482  1.79925798
2015 Q4   9.058873 715.1276 -5.00151422
2016 Q1 -22.434002 719.6999  5.36307197
2016 Q2  41.917620 724.7871 -2.70268212
2016 Q3 -28.542501 729.0107 -0.33223077
2016 Q4   9.058873 731.4376  5.08753509
2017 Q1 -22.434002 732.3260  0.07896622
2017 Q2  41.917620 731.6373 -0.85492859
2017 Q3 -28.542501 731.4799 -2.53736010
2017 Q4   9.058873 733.3012  0.83995997
2018 Q1 -22.434002 738.4447 -5.64069779
2018 Q2  41.917620 743.6182  2.23422722
2018 Q3 -28.542501 749.1186  0.83394758
```

However when I try to fit the data into auto.arima:

```
 fit <-auto.arima(y,xreg=x,seasonal=TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = FALSE,  
:  non-finite value supplied by optim
```

I get the **same error** when trying different specifications of auto.arima using same data:

```
fit <- Arima(y, xreg=x, order=c(2,0,0)) 
fit2 <-auto.arima(y,xreg=x,D=1)
```

**Question:** Why am I getting the error?  Am I skipping any steps in my use of auto.arima (differencing, seasonal adjustment, moving averages, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell exactly, because we don't have your data. (Next time, please use `dput()` to include your data. A picture is not very useful; few people will type the values or OCR the picture.) If we did have your data, this would likely entail some stepping through of `auto.arima()`.

However: recall that `auto.arima()` or `Arima()` with an `xreg` parameter [perform regression with ARIMA errors](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/). You have 13 observations and 16 explanatory variables. Unless some of the explanatory variables are collinear, you have an overparameterized system. The residuals will be almost perfectly zero (some rounding noise may occur). There will be very little for ARIMA to model.

I think you need to rethink your model and/or your data.

Comment: I updated the psot with dput().  I was under the impression that auto.arima would assist with feature selection.  Is this not the case?  Does auto.arima require features are selected in advance?  if so, how would approach feature selection and what criteria would you use.  Are there helpful R packages for time series feature selection?

Comment: No, `auto.arima()` does not do feature selection (it selects the ARIMA order using information criteria, but the regression is done on the full `xreg` matrix. You can see this if you inspect the code by simply typing `auto.arima`. For feature selection, you could use a lasso.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan Kolassa.  Do I need to de-trend and de-seasonalize (i.e., make stationary) my time series before using lasso for feature selection.  Or can I present the data as is (with trend and seasonality in tact).

Comment: You can try either way. Your detrending and deseasonalization may be confused by the regressors' influence, though, which is why `auto.arima()` first does the regression and then fits a (S)ARIMA model to residuals.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan Kolassa.  Last one - any reason you would not consider PCA 
(vs. lasso) for feature selection?

Comment: PCA is another possibility. I kind of don't like how it is hard to interpret.